# Get UIImage to show in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

My view does not show.

I created an empty application and added a button and an UIImageView.

I used storyboards. 
There is only one storyboard. 
An arrow points to this storyboard.

I set the rootViewController in the AppDelegate. I set the image below in the view controller.

The image is listed as 'bl_5_00' in the Images.xcassets blue folder.

A red button doesn't show either which leads me to believe I have messed something else up that is more structural.

**App Delegate**

```
#import "PEPI_AppDelegate.h"
#import "PEPI_LessonViewController.h"

@implementation PEPI_AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    PEPI_LessonViewController *controller = [[PEPI_LessonViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**View Controller**

```
#import "PEPI_LessonViewController.h"

@interface PEPI_LessonViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImage;

@end

@implementation PEPI_LessonViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIImage *imageYouWantToPass = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bl_5_00"];

    self.mainImage.image = imageYouWantToPass;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"bl_5_00"];
```

that means you are trying to fetch the image from an absolute file path, and here you are passing relative name which will not work. You can try instead..

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mailBundle] pathForResource:@"bl_5_00" ofType:@"png"];
```

OR

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bl_5_00.png"];
```

and then

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

**Edited**

To check whether the file is in your asset or, not try the following trick
just add

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bl_5_00" ofType:@"png"]);
```

It will log the full path of the image if exist, I suspect it is not added in your bundle so its not loading, you will get **(null)** if image doesn't exist. Try to re-add the image and clean build the app again.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: You should use `imageNamed:` instead. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727313/imagewithcontentsoffile-vs-imagenamed-imagewithcontentsoffile-return-a-low-qual

Comment: `imageNamed` should always be avoided if you have lots if image loading as it takes more memory than `imageWithContentsOfFile`. Yes imageNamed is easy to use but using a simple macro you can actually save lots of memory while dealing with images, just you need to append @2x in the filename.

Comment: @Tim: I switched to ImageNamed but it still does not work. The image is listed has 'bl_5_00' in the Images.xcassets blue folder.

Comment: @iphonic `imageNamed:` caches the image (so there's only a single instance in-memory) so it actually uses far less memory than `imageWithContentsOfFile:` if you're loading the same image more than once (and if you don't, then it still uses the same amount of memory).

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi Check my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @iphonic: I added that code and it prints null. I reverified the name is correct. Is there some way I need to link in the Images.xcassets?

Answer (score 1):

Image with content of file doesn't work if you pass image name. You can use imageNamed instead:

```
UIImage *imageYouWantToPass = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bl_5_00"];
```

I asume l_5_00 is name of the image and you added this file to your project (not just reference).

Comment: Correct, imageWithContentsOfFile requires a path to the image, while imageNamed just needs the name of the resource. Also, imageNamed loads automatically the retina version of the file, if available.

Comment: It is listed has 'bl_5_00' in the Images.xcassets blue folder.

Comment: I changed it to imageNamed but it still doesn't show. A red button doesn't show either which leads me to believe I have messed something else up that is more structural.

Comment: I cannot see any reference to redButton in your code. Have you made connection from storyboard do mainImage outlet? Try remove the image(file) from your project and add it again, remember to select copy image to dest.... check box.

Comment: @Greg Yes I made the connection using the IBOutlet via the CNTL+Click+Drag to Code. The images are all in the Images.xcassets. Does that help?

Comment: @Greg The red button is the next thing to handle, but I thought I should see the image first. One thing I don't understand is what the signifigance of adding a UI control to the storyboard is. Does this visual action automatically turn into code somewhere or is it sandboxed as only a visual layout to help a developer think about the application?

Comment: If you made the connection I believe you haven't check check boxy to copy image to project and you added the reference. Try remove the image from the project and try add it again, make sure the name is exact bl_5_00 plus extension (what kind of image is it?). If that doesn't help remove connection in storyboard and try add it again.

Comment: In short the visual from storyboard turn into the code. Have you change class to PEPI_LessonViewController in the storyboard for your view controller?

Comment: @Greg Yes I set the class as "PEPI_LessonViewController"