# Steps to launch an iOS app and show an image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been struggling with coding up a very simple app that launches and shows an image. The image is set programatically.

The steps I have tried:

1. Create empty application
2. Add ViewController & wire to AppDelegate
3. Add UIImageView
4. Set image.

I have code that doesn't work in a previous question:

[Get UIImage to show in UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360668/get-uiimage-to-show-in-uiimageview)

But that path did not work. If someone could outline the golden path of what I need to do I would be grateful.

Comment: Invert steps 3 and 4 and try again.  If it still doesn't work, post some more details.

Comment: Question to your last post - is the IBOutlet from an xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import "ViewControllerSimple.h"

@interface ViewControllerSimple ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerSimple



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Creat an image:
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"someImage.png"];

    //Creat UIImageView:
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    //Set its frame:
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];


    //Add to your view:
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}



@end
```

Is this what your looking for? or the AppDelegate is the problum? or creating a UIViewController?

Comment: I have this declared above: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImage;     Does that affect it?

Comment: Whenever you have property with IBOutlet, in means that it is placed on your "XIB" file, or in your case maybe the storyBourd. the only difference when doing that inset of programatically is, that you do not have to allocate it, just strait away call "[self. mainImage setImage:image]". And you do not need to set its frame too.